# Remotely Install Windows Updates and Software on Home network

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, remote-access

Is it possible to remotely install windows updates and software on my home network without having to login into each one with remote desktop?

I'm thinking of something like with ubuntu where I could just run an apt-get command via an ssh connection.

All pcs are running windows 7, I do not have a domain and there is no server version of windows running either on the network either.

Thanks

Comment: Logmein allows you to do this. Not on their free version though. From their management screen you can click updates and install them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a windows command line tool quite similar to apt-get:

You can try [WuInstall](http://www.wuinstall.com) (for installing updates the tool is free) in combination with psexec to remotely update machines, see http://www.wuinstall.com/index.php/faq#psexec

```
psexec \\server -c -s -u domain\administrator -p password \\share\path_to_wuinstall\WUInstall.exe /install
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just set every machine to automatically install updates?

[How to configure and use Automatic Updates in Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306525)

If you still want to manually start the updates you could use a script on each machine and trigger it remotely with psexec.

[Trigger Remote WUA to Install Updates](http://slecluyse.wordpress.com/2010/09/17/trigger-remote-wua-to-install-updates/)

Answer (score 1):

There's an app called [BatchPatch](http://batchpatch.com) that will do exactly what you're looking for. The free evaluation version allows up to 7 remote hosts to be patched simultaneously.